# vs code file explorer take full screen width how to fix

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image of the vs code file explorer take full screen width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs1qb.png)

Hello ,  i am not able to fix this problem the problem is that the vs code file explorer take full screen with i can't able to fix it. also the picture i have uploaded here.

i mean the file explorer where it the left side of vs code where our file are present in a structure or herarical way this taked the full screen with and i am not able to open a file because it take the while screen

I am also tried it but nothing working **Crtl + B** , and i have closed and reopened but also not working

so please help me in fixing i. i am the begginner to stack overflow.

so this is the problem i have described above

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by going to customize layout, and selecting justify.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset all of your VsCode settings with editing your user `.json` file. For doing this follow these steps:

1. Press `Ctrl+Shift+P`
2. Type in the command line '`Open User Settings (JSON)`'
3. Delete all the text which opened after typing second step.
4. Save the file with `Ctrl+S`